Move to Staging area feature
Questions are expectedly arriving from new users and bypassing the staging area.  Would it be useful to include a button, say beside the close button, to move the question to the staging area?  This could be handled with multiple votes or with special privileges as with duplicates.  This would especially be helpful if the staging area contained easy access to canned messages and links offering suggestions on question improvement.

The limit on the number of questions going to the staging area is based on the number of people willing to review. How do you propose not to flood the system with so many questions that you'll get a backlog that will never clear.

@RobertLongson Well, the backlog will exist whether there is a staging area or not as responding to any question is voluntary. Perhaps the staging area is just a bad idea.  But essentially we now have two staging areas.

That's by design

It sounds like a nice idea, but as robert mentioned, scaling/throughput issues are a thing, and then once you think about it, we already have closure, and to an extent, closure and SG have effectively the same purposes. Assuming you'd need a similar send-to-SG vote count, closure seems sufficient to me. There are some design differences, such as comments in SG staying in SG, but it's not clear to me right now whether that's desirable for questions that didn't start from SG.

So I guess new users have two staging areas since it's "by design." But If there does become to much of a backup then the users may probably stop using it.

In theory, the staging ground is supposed to be for all questions from new users. But this requires the amount of reviewers to rise to meet the demand. (Although demand has admittedly been trending downward since 2014, and AI gave it a further nudge.)
